# Angular controllers: confused about the '$scope' parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <h1>{{carname}}</h1>

</div>

<script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.carname = "Volvo";
 });
</script>
```

I thought `$scope` is merely the name of a parameter for the anonymous function, and you can't just assign it properties (`carname`) without it passing an object as the argument.

So does Angular automatically create an argument called something like `myCtrlScope` to pass to the `$scope` parameter? Otherwise, I don't see any way that an actually object is being passed to `$scope`, which is merely a parameter.

Comment: $scope in already defined by AngualrJS developers, whenever we use it in our code, angular automatically came to know and inject it dependency. This concept in known as dependency injection further you can read [this](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjH5srUuYLTAhWEaxQKHZ11CBgQFggXMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.angularjs.org%2Fguide%2Fdi&usg=AFQjCNFnywa5rLhpd14MLfHHNAmkQbjs5w&sig2=bdJ5Y9iVZ--H78R0xrgudQ&bvm=bv.151325232,d.bGs) for better understanding.

Comment: This is explained very clearly in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote the controller can be written as like this also:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', [ "$scope", function($scope) {
   $scope.carname = "Volvo";
}]);
```

The way you declared is short-hand method. The way you mentioned is not wrong but the better way to declare is the above method where we specify each of the dependencies. You can check on documentation for [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) for better clarification.

Answer (score 0):

use this Inline Array Annotation like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1>{{carname}}</h1>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.carname = "volvo";   
}]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```